Why is StreamReader including escape characters in its output for a line?
I am reading a txt file with StreamReader and it appears to be outputting escape characters. I am using the following code:
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(saveLocation, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}

When I open the txt file manually the line in question reads value_start "FILE_NAME", but the line value in Visual Studio that gets saved to my data structure is " value_start \"FILE_NAME\"". I believe the escape characters are being included, but in my research on this topic StreamReader should ignore escape characters.
My file is being written like so:
private static void WriteIndexFile(
     string saveLocation,
     SortedDictionary<string, string> filesToWrite)
  {
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveLocation, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
     {
        writer.WriteLine("cross_ref");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in filesToWrite)
        {
           writer.WriteLine($"  file_start \"{kvp.Key}\"");
           writer.WriteLine($"     filename \"{kvp.Value}\"");
           writer.WriteLine($"     #modified {File.GetLastWriteTime(kvp.Value).ToString()}");
           writer.WriteLine($"  file_end");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("end_cross_ref");
     }
  }

Is there anything I'm doing wrong when writing or reading my files that would be causing the escape characters to be read?
EDIT
It appears I was not clear what I actually need. The issue is that because the escape characters show up in the lines when I read the file, it is being saved to a variable with the escape characters. When I then compare that variable, which should be a complete file path, to the files I get from Directory.GetFiles(), they do not equal each other even though they should.
For example, "C:data\local\files\file_name.txt" from Directory.GetFiles() is compared to "\"C:data\local\files\file_name.txt\"" and the strings are not equal. If the escape characters were not present in the latter, they would be.
How can I update my code to not include escape characters?

You're seeing this in Visual Studio while debugging, or in your output text files? Visual Studio shows escapes when viewing strings in the debugger, they shouldn't be output to the actual file you're writing with the stream writer. edit: click the magnifying glass to the right of the value in the debugger and it'll show it unescaped.

I suggest opening the file in Notepad. As @Evelyn says, I bet it will show correctly.

@Evelyn thanks for the suggestion. Opening it in Notepad, etc. does display the lines correctly, but the issue is I am reading the lines and comparing them inside in the program, and as a result the lines being read from the file with the escape characters don't equal the file paths I get using Directory.GetFiles(). I will update my question accordingly.

@SpencePro Again, that's just the debugger trying to be helpful. It's not actually how the strings are loaded in memory.

Escape characters are a C# syntax thing. They don't exist in the string. Your issues probably stem from how you read the string with quotes, and compare them to a string that isn't quoted. But I'd have to see the full reading code for sure.

We need a minimal, reproducible example with the writing to file, reading from the file, and checking for equality to help you. You are the one putting in the quotes here filename \"{kvp.Value}\", c#/.NET are not doing that. Directory.GetFiles does not return quotes so your output string and a string from get files won't be equal. Either stop putting quotes in your output, or add quotes when you check your read in file against Directory.GetFiles, or strip off the quotes when you read the line back in.

@EtiennedeMartel thank you, you are right. I was confused by the way it was presenting information. Stripping the double quotes from the lines before saving them to my collection made the comparison later work as intended.
